# Angular.js interpolation in filter parameter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a filter on a `ng-repeat`, which accepts a parameter. It currently works with a string.

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in searchData | aboutFilter:'abo'">
```

Is is possible to use an interpolated value in place of the string?

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in searchData | aboutFilter:'{{list.api}}'">
```

Here is my filter:

```
app.filter('aboutFilter', function() {
return function(items, input) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function (value,key) {

      if(key===input){            
        filtered.push(value);
      }
    });
    return filtered;
}
});
```

Here is the complete template logic:

```
<ul ng-repeat="list in englishList">

  <a ng-class="{{list.title}}Hide" mobile-search-slide href="/about"><li><p>{{list.title}}</p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></li></a>

  <ul id="hideMe" ng-class="'hide{{list.title}}'">           
  <div ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in searchData | aboutFilter:'{{list.api}}'">

   <div ng-repeat="result in value" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'">
     <a ng-href="{{value.title}}/{{result.shortname}}">
       <li>
           <p>{{result.title}}</p><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
       </li>
     </a>
    </div>  

  </div> 
  </li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: remove brackets - just aboutFilter:list.api

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Comment: @byrdr have you also removed the single quotes? How doesn't it work?

Comment: make a plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/nn6mneFt1zJhI0v5gZCG?p=preview u see it works

Comment: You can just mention the model name, it will work. No need to use `{{}}`. Also in your filter code is matching `key` with `input`, here `key` is 0,1,etc index of item and you're doing strict comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use some `ng-model`for filter, then you can just use the `model` name. No need to use `{{}}` expression.

In your case, it will be :

```
 <div ng-cloak ng-repeat="(key, value) in searchData | aboutFilter:list.api">
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lebesemadi/1/edit?html,js,output)**

Remember in your filter, you are using string comparison. So the filter will check for exact matches.

And also, IN your filter:

You are comparing `key` with the `input list.api`. Here key will always be `0,1, etc` index. You must be using `value` there instead of `key`